# How to find a value anywhere in code using the Chrome Debugger?

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, web

Using the chrome debugger, is there any way to pause the execution when a specific value is found anywhere in the code ?

I'm not talking about a conditional breakpoint per se, because you have to set them up on a specific line, instead I would like the debugger to break whenever a specific value is found in memory, for every possible line / variable.